# PHP - foreach loops - $arr and &$value as same variable

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach($foo as &$bar) {
  //do something
}
```

This is the syntax for a foreach loop in PHP. Usually, `$foo` & `$bar` are different variables, but my question is can they be the same variable? I'm asking if PHP will let me, not whether it is possible to write the code like that. I know this would modify the variable inside the loop, and I'm not worried about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "being the same variable"? Like `foreach ($foo as $foo)`? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Yes, and yes, it seems to work. I was just wondering if you're supposed to be able to. Plus, I used PyroCMS, so it might have been that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work, ONCE, but only because of a quirk in PHP:

```
php > $x = array(1,2,3);
php > foreach($x as $x) { echo $x; }
123
php > var_dump($x);
int(3)
```

Note that the loop actually ran for all 3 values of the original `$x` array, but after the loop exits, `$x`, is now a mere int - it's no longer an array.

This holds true if the `as $x` is a straight plain $x variable, or a `&$x` reference.

Comment: Would this work if the 2nd $x is a regular variable, not a reference? Usually, when the $bar in the foreach loop (in my example) is a reference, it changes the $foo after the loop, but when it's a plain variable, it doesn't.

Comment: doesn't matter if you're using `as $x` or `as &$x`. the result is the same. $x will be the LAST value in the original array when the loop exits.

Comment: Does this work if the loop variables are different, or only when they're the same? That is a very interesting quirk.

Comment: if they're different, e.c. `foreach($array as $value)` then there's no problem. $value will simply be the last value in $array that was processed, and $array is unchanged. if you have `as &$value`, then $value is a reference to the LAST value in the array processed, and if you assign something to $value later on, you'll be modifying the array.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works. When a `foreach` loop starts, it makes a snapshot of the array contents. Then the iteration variable is successively assigned to the elements of that snapshot.

```
$foo = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($foo as &$foo) {
  echo "foreach: $foo\n";
}
echo "vardump: ";
var_dump($foo);
```

Outputs:

```
foreach: 1
foreach: 2
foreach: 3
vardump: int(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot be the same variable; `$foo` would be an array and `&$bar` would be the reference to an element of that array. That's why it's called a *for-each loop*, because it's looping through the elements of an array and, in this case, modifying them directly (because you are using references).

Comment: &$bar is not a reference to an element of the array, it's the array itself. The "element of that array" you talk about is in a single iteration of the loop, not the whole loop. Please know what you're talking about when you say something.

Comment: @trysis No, `&$bar` is _not_ the array itself unless you are doing `foreach ($foo as &$foo) { ... }`.

Comment: How can &$bar be the array and not the array? You're contradicting yourself.